# how to allow ' character in OData endpoint URL

Tags: c#, character-encoding, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I have OData endpoint to do filter for the client first and last name if the entity exists. the problem happens when the user use ' character inside the name string and that will break OData URI parser 
my test string will be

> http://localhost.com/Clients?$filter=FirstName eq 'test'20001' and
>   LastName eq 'test20001'

my stack trace

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. There is an unterminated string literal at position 23 in 'FirstName eq 'test20001'.",
        "innererror": {
            "message": "There is an unterminated string literal at position 23 in 'FirstName eq 'test20001'.",
            "type": "Microsoft.OData.ODataException",
            "stacktrace": "   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ExpressionLexer.NextToken()\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.UriQueryExpressionParser.ParseComparison()\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.UriQueryExpressionParser.ParseLogicalAnd()\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.UriQueryExpressionParser.ParseLogicalOr()\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.UriQueryExpressionParser.ParseExpression()\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.UriQueryExpressionParser.ParseExpressionText(String expressionText)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ODataQueryOptionParser.ParseFilterImplementation(String filter, ODataUriParserConfiguration configuration, ODataPathInfo odataPathInfo)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ODataQueryOptionParser.ParseFilter()\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Query.FilterQueryOption.get_FilterClause()\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Query.Validators.FilterQueryValidator.Validate(FilterQueryOption filterQueryOption, ODataValidationSettings settings)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Query.FilterQueryOption.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Query.Validators.ODataQueryValidator.Validate(ODataQueryOptions options, ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ValidateQuery(HttpRequestMessage request, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object response, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, ODataQueryContext queryContext)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try  `eq "test''20001"`

Comment: that can fix it but how I sanitize the ' to '' in code using javascript

Comment: like this `var Url = "http://localhost.com/Clients?$filter=FirstName eq \"test\'20001\" and LastName eq \'test20001\'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this how I fix it

```
var filter = '$filter=FirstName eq \'' + escapeString(self.selectedClient().FirstName())
                function escapeString(string) {
                    string = string.replace(/'/g, '\'\'');
                    string = string.replace(/&/g, '%26');
                    return string;
                }
```